# How to add parameter in the html form action?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="studyresults.show" method="POST">
   ...
   ...
   <div style="clear: both;float: right;padding-top: 15px;padding-bottom:5px;">
          <input id="submitButton" style="float:right;margin-top:-80px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" />
        </div>
```

I want to add a parameter from url string like this:

```
<script>
function getQueryStringValue (key) {
          return decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + encodeURIComponent(key).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));
        }
</script>
```

I would like to query the url with "token" string so I can pass "token" as part of POST request parameter when I click submit button. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I believe the standard way is to add an invisible `<input name="token">`; you could set its `value` in an `onsubmit` callback.

Comment: can i call this function directly in value? i.e. `value = getQueryStringValue("token")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using JSP, there's no need to involve JavaScript here. You can pull any query string parameter value directly using JSP's EL *expression language*.

```
<form action="studyresults.show" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="${param.token}" />
    ...
    <div style="clear: both;float: right;padding-top: 15px;padding-bottom:5px;">
        <input id="submitButton" style="float:right;margin-top:-80px;"
               type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The above example adds the `token` value `${param.token}` as a hidden `<input>` field which will get POSTed along with other field values when the form is submitted.

Comment: Does `param.token` get value from the current url it is on? For instance, if the form is in `https://test.com/token=abc`, `param.token` becomes abc?

EDIT: It does work. Thanks!